# Redirection after submitting duplicate comment

Tags: php

Sometimes, when posting comments, duplicate comments appear (hosting is very busy ). im use `add_filter('comment_flood_filter', '__return_false');`

How to not display "Duplicate comment detected" but redirect to post? Without adding a duplicate comment to the database.

In other words - count only one comment, and if the same is found, then redirect to the post.

Comment: by returning false you're essentially preventing handling of duplicate comments but your question is asking how can you handle them - I'm not sure it's clear what you're looking to achieve

Comment: I clarified the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer lets you redirect back to the originating post instead of `die`ing with the flood message.  It's a PHP class, not just a simple function. You can copy-paste this into your `functions.php` as-is, or set it up in whichever way you like to manage your custom code.

- assumes PHP 5.3+
- it also contains code for duplicate comments which your original question mentioned, but then you edited it out. You can remove this bit by deleting the line that contains `add_action( 'comment_duplicate_trigger,` ...

```php
class Handle_Comment_Flood {

    private $comment_post_id;

    public function __construct() {
        add_filter( 'preprocess_comment', [ $this, 'capture_post_id' ], 10, 1 );

        add_action( 'comment_flood_trigger', [ $this, 'handle_redirect' ], 0, 0 );
        add_action( 'comment_duplicate_trigger', [ $this, 'handle_redirect' ], 0, 0 );
    }

    public function capture_post_id( $comment ) {
        $this->comment_post_id = isset( $comment[ 'comment_post_ID' ] ) ? $comment[ 'comment_post_ID' ] : 0;
        return $comment;
    }

    public function handle_redirect() {
        if ( !empty( $this->comment_post_id ) ) {
            wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( get_post( $this->comment_post_id ) ) );
            die();
        }
    }
}

new Handle_Comment_Flood();
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. But doesn't work((( Please looking. A freshly installed test site. http://sitework.epizy.com FTP Hostname: ftpupload.net Port: 21 FTP Username: epiz_28828400 FTP Password: kfzX88ywI211oY Wordpress Console: Username: admin Password: 12345678 Code this ...wp-content/themes/iconic-one/functions.php

Comment: you should not provide public FTP access + password - you should remove that

Comment: This is a test site, there is nothing there.

Comment: You just shouldn't be providing public access like that.  Anyways, whichever you prefer.  I've updated the code a little. Please replace the code you have with this current code.  I've just tested it and it works exactly as intended for a new WP site.  You must include this to ensure it always gets executed early enough... directly at the end of your `functions.php` should suffice.

Comment: When trying to post a duplicate comment: "Duplicate comment detected; it looks as though you’ve already said that!"

Comment: This has been tested to work on a new, clean WP site, adding this code to the `functions.php`. Either you're not adding it correctly, or there's something else interferring.

Comment: I also entered the code on the new clean site. There are no more changes at all.

Comment: I added a `die()` in `handle_redirect()` function. Does that fix it for you?

Comment: Yes, it works now. Can I redirect to a comment? Example: ...name-post/#comment-...

Comment: Not in this... There's no way to know the comment beforehand. Can you click to accept the answer please?

Comment: Thanks for the help!